# What HDD diagnostic tool to trust?

Tags: external-hard-drive, diagnostic

I recently purchased external HDD (Samsung M3 Portable External Drive 1TB). I run basic diagnostic tests with SeaTools for Windows and unfortunately Short DST and Short Generic tests fail.

I then passed the HDD to shop service and their engineer checked HDD with Victoria and HD Tune tools - no issues detected (no bad blocks, good speed and temperature). He said that the disk is fine and I should not worry about SeaTools tests.

Is it true and the disk is really probably fine? Or I should try to return/exchange HDD by warranty?

Comment: what do your SMART stats say? I use speedfan (in windows) to read the stats off my drive.

Comment: If the manufacturer tool says it fails tests then you should trust that tool mainly for warranty reasons

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion about SMART. Probably it doesn't matter in my case, because I just guessed to check error code, returned by SeaTools. Its tests fail in the beginning because SeaTools can't validate HDD serial number. Probably because this is Samsung drive, not Seagate. I am now sure that the drive is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it was a seagate then the use of sea tools would get you a way to deal with seagate warrenty replacement. It is a samsung, which probably uses different firmware.
 If you have any smart output and read the actual "data" (meaning sometimes the tools are not always giving the right info for all drives) then what you sea :-) is what you get. It should be sufficient.

Is there a reason originally for you to have tested it?    If it is me, and I suspect that a hard drive might be having some issues, I rely less on these software tools, and give it a real job to do instead.  I could fill the disk with specific data from another drive, and do a "compare" of the data between the 2 drives. A full loading and compare might take some time to do, but reality is more complete.

Comment: Thank you. I guessed to check SeaTools error code and it is equal to 6C9AC2A4, which means "Serial number not detected, SeaTools did fail the drive". I've rechecked the serial number on Seagate site and it also is not accepted. Probably because this is a Samsung drive. So you are right, the manufacturer makes sense in that case.

Comment: I've checked the drive just to detect possible problems earlier. It's new drive, so I had not any problem with them.